# Can't use SFML sprite drawing and OpenGL rendering at the same time

Tags: opengl, sfml

I'm using some SFML built in functions to draw sprites and text as an overlay on top of some OpenGL rending in an SFML RenderWindow. The opengl rendering appears fine until I add the code to draw the sprites or text. The sprite or text drawing causes the OpenGL stuff to disappear.

The follow code show what I'm trying to do

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(viewport.width,viewport.height,32), "SFML Window");
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0,viewport.width,0,viewport.height,0,1);

while (window.pollEvent(Event))
    {
    //event handling...

    //begin drawing
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(col.x,col.y,col.z);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        glVertex2f(pos.x+verts[i].x,pos.y+verts[i].y);
    glEnd();


    // adding this line causes all the  previous opengl triangles not to appear
    window.draw("Sometext");


    window.display();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats happening is that SFML also uses  OpenGL to draw the text (or sprites) in 2D. So drawing of the text by SFML usually messes up whatever OpenGL state that you are using for you own OpenGL drawing.

SFML RenderWindow provides a pair of methods which allow you to 'save' the current OpenGL state onto a stack and restore the saved state from the stack. Just wrap the SFML drawing code with window.pushGLStates(); and  window.popGLStates(); as in the code below.

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(viewport.width,viewport.height,32), "SFML Window");
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0,viewport.width,0,viewport.height,0,1);

while (window.pollEvent(Event))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(col.x,col.y,col.z);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        glVertex2f(pos.x+verts[i].x,pos.y+verts[i].y);
    glEnd();

    window.pushGLStates(); //save the current OpenGL state
    window.draw("Sometext");

    window.popGLStates(); //restore the saved OpenGL state to the way it was before we drew the text

    window.display();
}
```